# What does bootstrap.min.css contains, and how can i overrite it with my costume css file?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My main problem is that I get a default a bootsrrap design, and i can't change it.
I 've read many places that I have to do something like this:

```
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I 've figured out that i need to use this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

but with this method I can't change any of my elements. Nobody writes it down, what does the bootstrap.min.css contains. Is it a standard library, or I have to put into it some data. Sorry for the dumb question...

Comment: what do you want to change?

Comment: Navbar mostly. But i can't get it why it refers to bootsrap.min.css like a local file. I should create one, or it is a part of the bootstrap framework which i indirectly using like a plug in?

Comment: well if you have it locally you should use the local path... if not the cdn one

Answer (score 1):

Do not modify the bootstrap.css!

the approach you mentioned first is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the right method. Run bootstrap then run your custom code afterwards to overwrite bootstrap styles.

In terms of knowing what you are overwriting, all the documentation for the bootstrap CSS is contained here:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Alternatively you can look at the [non-minified version](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download), or inspect elements in the browser.

Definitely do not modify the bootstrap library. This will make it difficult to get general bootstrap help as you have a customised version, and you'll never be able to upgrade the library without removing your changes.

As a general rule, never modify a third party library which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify default bootstrap.css bcoz it contains much css which will used in coding and designing, rather write or overwrite with your own custom css new a new file

Answer (score 0):

you are using correct method. some times css not override. so use !important to force override. 
eg: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/